# Trying to get validate function to work with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have tried this before on another application and just copied the code over and edited the paths, and things I need to for this application. I am not getting any errors, but I cannot seem to get this to work. It doesn't show any error messages or apply my classes to the inputs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

class Signin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const { meta: {touched, error} } = field;
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label><strong>{field.label}:</strong></label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          { touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit({email, password}) {
    console.log(email, password);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
        <Field
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  //Validate the inputs from values
  if(!values.email) {
    errors.title = "Enter an email!";
  }
  if(!values.password) {
    errors.categories = "Enter a password!";
  }
  //If errors is empty, the form is fine to submit
  //If errors has any properties, redux form assumes form is invalid
  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'signin'
})(connect(null, actions)(Signin));
```

Comment: It may be a little confusing when I am referring to not getting any errors. I mean not getting any errors in the console or related to the coding side of the app. The errors from the validation (the ones I want to show up) are not showing up either.

Comment: In the validate function do a console.log(errors) and check whether it is giving the correct result or not

Comment: You my friend are a genius! I did the console log and realized they were attached to errors.title, and errors.categories still. I needed to switch them to errors.email, errors.password!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is with Validate function where the error log is attached since the error maps to title and categories whereas the Field name is email and password

Use

```
function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  //Validate the inputs from values
  if(!values.email) {
    errors.email = "Enter an email!";
  }
  if(!values.password) {
    errors.password = "Enter a password!";
  }
  //If errors is empty, the form is fine to submit
  //If errors has any properties, redux form assumes form is invalid
  return errors;
}
```